# C++ read text file in accordance with the encoding

Tags: c++, file, boost

I know that file encoding is hard to determine. But is there a somehow working solution for this problem in C++? Mb boost does (I did not find any appropriate)?.

I need to determine the encoding of the file and read its first line to a string of appropriate locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any decent solution. I will try to explain. You can only define encoding if you more or less know that should be in a file. Then you can try to guess converting file differently and check if result looks like you expected. If you take as example Russian encoding tables. You have all type of variations like KOI-8, CP1251, CP866 and it's not the end =). All those encoding have different mapping for Russian symbols, so if you take a text file and read it consider wrong encoding instead of proper data you will have words formed from absolutely different letters, although words/spaces and lower ASCII table part will look absolutely fine.

Regarding UTF8/16 etc you cannot detect it, but you can check that input file has no illegal sequences inside, so you can try to treat it using certain encoding.

I think best option will be at first try to define subset of encodings you plan to detect and design detection algorithm based on certain criteria.